# Why do you have to explicitly declare a GridViewRow's type in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

In Visual Studio 2015 (.NET 4.5, ASP.NET C#) the following compiles and runs:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridView.Rows)
{
    Thread.Sleep(row.Cells.Count);
}
```

But this does not (`Cells` is not a valid method):

```
foreach (var row in gvEdit.Rows)
{
    Thread.Sleep(row.Cells.Count);
}
```

Is this a limitation of `var`? I don't mind explicitly typing it, I just expected it to work with `var`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Rows` is a [GridViewRowCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrowcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) which implements `ICollection` and `IEnumerable`, but not the generic versions `ICollection<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`. It's a hold over from the pre-generic days.

[This from Eric Lippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern/) adds some background to how `foreach` works.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Had my gears grinding for about 10 minutes.